# Mute someone in a discord dm call using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

So, I wanted to create a script that mutes a person in a dm call(client-side), but I can't seem to find anything online about it. Does anyone know how to do such thing? And is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't mute someone in DMs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.